# What http status code to return for "invalid state change"

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

This is a question about best REST practices. 
Considering the controller below which has a method which is supposed to update an application object.

```
public ApplicationController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationService _applicationService;
    public ApplicationController(ApplicationService applicationService)
    {
       _applicationService = applicationService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBodey] Application application)
    {
         var previousApplication = _applicationService.Get(applicationId)
         if(application.State == ApplicationState.Approved
             && apreviousApplcation.State != ApplicationState.Pending)
         {
              return StatusCode(*what code here*, "State have to be pending to goto approved");
         }

         _applicationSerivce.Update(application);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

What status code would be best to return if it is not possible to change the state of the application to the new state?

Comment: No so easy. I suggest a 400 with a body text. Its not really a resource more  a validation.

Comment: From MDN: "The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to *invalid syntax*. The client should not repeat this request without modification." (my *emphasis*) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 
My case is not invalid syntax

Comment: True, but as far as I know there is no response code for validator errors, there will alway be a compromise.
A "442 Unprocessable Entity" is another option

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply. I feel that it is easy to run into ambiguities when trying to make the most out of http status code in REST implementations. If you convert your comment into an answer I can mark it as accepted. There doesn't seem to be much competition about answering this question :)

Answer (score 5):

Have look here https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html in the level 3 section

Fowler uses a 409 Conflict header to indicate that something went wrong.

Comment: Hm, my perception of 409 is that it has to do with concurrency check. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#409 But there seems to be no exact pattern to follow...